# Are black holes an infinite source of energy?

Tags: energy, black-holes, mass, potential-energy, mass-energy

Black holes are considered particularities because in a determined point in time they are pointless, as consequence there are some mass in a null space so the density become infinite. Finally if energy is equal to mass, that is mean a black hole has an infinite energy? Is that possible?

Comment: Infinite density does not mean infinite mass. Black holes have a finite mass, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25802/

Answer (score 1):

No, the energy of a black hole is not infinite. It depends on its mass, angular momentum and charge. Infinite density at a point does not translate to infinite energy in the $E=mc^2$ sense.

It is in fact possible to extract energy from black holes by exploiting certain properties of accretion disks or ergospheres, but this is a finite process.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is that $$E = mc^2$$. Density, however, is given by $$density = \dfrac{mass}{volume}$$
Thus, if volume = 0, then density is infinite. Black holes have a finite mass. It is there density which is finite because all the mass is at a single point (singularity, volume = 0).